# Projectile motion of the water surface from water discharging from a pipe

Tags: fluid-dynamics, projectile

I am looking at pipe flow into a pit. How do I calculate the outside water surface path.

I understand how to calculate projectile motion from calculus in terms of a velocity, point object and projectile angle however I do not know how to add thickness and calculate the outside path.

We can ignore drag force unless someone can provide suggested values based on field or lab validation.

Also I can accept that it will be hard to calculate the expansion of water discharging from the pipe into the pit so unless someone knows suggested values from field or lab validation then this can also be ignored.

Comment: cross-section or thickness from continuity equation.

Comment: Continuity is not going to tell me too much because all it says (in steady flow) is flow in equals flow out nothing about the hydraulic grade line. So going back to the original question, if know what my pipe diameter is, assuming full pipe flow and I know what my velocity is what is the equation to calculate at least the top surface level level discharging into the stormwater pit.

Comment: the projectile motion is almost same as for a solid body imo.

Comment: So assume the point projectile motion is at center of mass (ie centre of pipe) assuming no expansion of the water the projectile motion of the outer water surface is Offset by haf the pipe. Do you know how to calculate expansion of the water as it discharges into the pit.

Comment: what do you mean by expansion?

Comment: When water is under pressure and flowing through a pipe. When the water is discharged directly to the atmosphere it while expand in width (the flowrate is constant however the density drops because the water is mixing with the atmosphere). In the case of a stormwater pipe discharging into a pit this would probably be minimumal.